# How to end the `read` command by ctrl c?

Tags: shell, fish, trap

```
read -l -P "" number
if test -z "$number"
    set number 2
end
# do something e.g. echo "Processed"
echo "Processed"
```

I want to read something from the standard input and then do something, e.g. echo "Processed". When `Ctrl C` is inputted from the standard input, I wish `do something` will never be executed. However, `do something` is always be executed.

I tried to use trap to `kill %self`, like

```
trap 'kill %self' INT
read -l -P "" number
if test -z "$number"
    set number 2
end
# do something e.g. echo "Processed"
echo "Processed"
```

However, `%self` should not be killed. This program is triggered by a shortcut. The pid of the program of the same as the pid of the terminal. Thus when `kill %self` is executed, the terminal is been closed. This is not expected.

[The pid of the program of the same as the pid of the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APezp.png)

Comment: See https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/trap.html. The `trap` command doesn't execute the function. So capturing its output via `set number (trap...)` doesn't make any sense. The `trap` command also only exists for backward compatibility with POSIX shells. You should be using the event handler pattern: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#event. It is also unclear what value you expect `number` to hold before and after a Ctrl-C (SIGINT) event.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `read` reads from the terminal and gets a ctrl-c, it is already aborted [0].

However, in that case it sets the variable to empty and returns a false status.

You never check that status, and so execution just continues with an empty variable.

What you want is simply this:

```
read -l -P "" number
or exit # or return or handling it in another way.
```

You can also use an `if`:

```
if read -l -P "" number
   # do things you would do if read wasn't aborted
   # Note: $number can still be empty if the user just pressed enter!
end
```

---

[0]: When you read from e.g. a pipe, the ctrl-c would typically end the writing process, and so read would get an end-of-file instead of a newline, and the same thing would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to capturing how many times Ctrl-C has been pressed. I don't know if this answers your question because your question is ambiguous about what value you expect `$number` to hold before and after a Ctrl-C (SIGINT) event. In the example below I pressed Ctrl-C twice after defining the `ctrl_c_handler` function.

```
> function ctrl_c_handler --on-signal INT
      echo "ctrl c" %self
      set -g number (math $number + 1)
   end
> ctrl c 37990
> echo $number
1
> ctrl c 37990
> echo $number
2
```